# Sublime text: edit all occurrences of variable without highlighting

Tags: sublime-text

In Sublime Text, you can edit all occurrences of a word by highlighting the words with `alt+F3`, and then typing whatever you want to change the word to. Is there a way to edit the multiple occurrences of the word without having to specifically highlight it?

Comment: Other than using ctrl+h "Replace All" ? You can also use "Tools" -> New Snipplet to write scipt to automatically replace words.

Answer (score 3):

If you have your mouse caret (blinking pipe | ) on a word and you press <kbd>ctrl-d</kbd> (Windows) or <kbd>cmd-d</kbd> (Mac) you can select the current word & if you press <kbd>ctrl-d</kbd> afterwards that it will select other repeat occurences of your selection.

[GIF: Atom edit multiple occurrences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2J9M.gif)